# Is there a Spring Data REST equivalent for GraphQL schemas?

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-graphql

Is there an equivalent to Spring Data REST for GraphQL?
More specifically a library that automatically generates GraphQL schemas and query-, schema- and batch-mappings based on a noSQL schema in the database.

Similar to https://www.boosterframework.com/ (*"and even generates a **fully-working GraphQL API** for you – don't even mind about writing the resolvers or maintaining your GraphQL schema, it will do that for you too."*)

I am trying to automate the process of GraphQL queries in Spring Boot.